# Instruction to calculate the integral representation of the Hankel functions

Tags: special-functions, contour-integration

I was wondering if anyone can help me on how to calculate the integral representation of Hankel function mentioned above Fig 9. on page 178 of ["Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions" written by Watson](https://archive.org/details/treatiseontheory00watsuoft/page/178/mode/2up?ref=ol&view=theater).

[Here is the image of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOK3c.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "calculating" the integral representation?

Comment: By the way, you just have to read the book, the derivation is there. It starts with the derivation of the corresponding formula for $J_\nu(z)$ on page 175. Then on the top of pages 177-178, Watson proves the analogous formula for $Y_\nu(z)$. Finally, on page 178, it is proved for the Hankel functions.

Comment: Can you help me on how can I calculate this contour integral using Couchy's theorem. Should I create closed loops to calculate this integration?@Gary

Comment: Do you want to calculate it numerically?  If you are only intersted in calculating the Hankel function, there are many other integral representations for it, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9 Otherwise you can take the following path for integration: go from $-\infty$ to $0$, then from $0$ up to $\pi i$, finally from $\pi i$ go to $+\infty+\pi i$ along a straight line paralel to the positive real line.

Comment: I want to derive the solution of the integral analytically using the complex variable theory. How should I go through these path? Should the residue theorem be used for this calculation? As I calculated using mathematica the integrand does not have any poles.@Gary

Comment: The solution is the Hankel function. It is a special function that cannot be expressed in simple terms.  They are solutions of the Bessel equation, read https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2 You may use power series expansions, numerical integration or asymptotic expansions to compute the Hankel function.

Comment: I know. As I understood from your explanations, the proof in the reverse way i.e. from Integral representation to Hankel function can not be done. Am I correct?@Gary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132038/discussion-between-gary-and-alex97).